# Changing value of a dropdown list from another controller

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-scope

I am having a json for filling the dropdown list.
At first the first item of the dropdown menu is the first item of json data.
But i need to update the element by $scope variable of another coontroller.This $scope variable is getting data from service call.
**Code for dropdown menu-**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select ng-model="funcLoc1item" style="width:63%;text-align:center;" ng-change="onchangefuncLoc1()"  ng-options="item.firstName as item.firstNamefor item in funcLoc1List">
    </select>
</div>
```

Code of controller of the same page in which dropdown is there.

```
var funcLoc1 = {[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]};

$scope.funcLoc1List=funcLoc1;
$scope.funcLoc1item=$scope.funcLoc1List[0].firstName;
$rootScope.funcLoc1item=$scope.funcLoc1List[0].firstName;

$scope.onchangefuncLoc1 = function() {

    var selectedValue = $scope.funcLoc1item;
    $rootScope.funcLoc1item = selectedValue;
    alert(selectedValue);
};
```

Till now everything is fine.BBut now i want to pass a $scope variable from another controller.This variable should now be the default element of dropdown.
For rxample,in the code by default when the page loads **John** will be default element in dropdown.After sometime now i will get some value in variable of another controller for example i got $scope.xyz="anna".so now i need to change the default element of dropdown to 2nd item of the list that is anna.

This is the link for a demo.i want the value which i get in button click to set the default value in dropdown list.

[TRYING LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8fkBArMemXRhqJ09NvU?p=preview)

Comment: Would recommend a service or factory to pass between controllers.

Comment: okkk...but use getproperty and setproperty in service but i need to change dropdown list.How to decide when to call the service...changing value in other controller cant trigger a service in another controller.

Comment: it can trigger from any controller, that's the point

Comment: store an object (model) in the service. You can set values in the service object from controller A or controller B. The view should then automatically update. Of course, you need to use object not string in your view